# bad operand types for binary operator '<=' , '+='

Tags: java

I don't understand why my binary operands are not working for if statements. For example I get the error, bad operand types for binary operator '<='. First type: double[] Second type: double for if(prices <=5.00)

```
public class Prices2
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
double[] prices = {2.45, 7.85, 1.35, 1.55, 4.05, 9.55, 4.55, 1.45, 7.85, 1.25, 5.55, 10.95, 8.55,
2.85, 11.05, 1.95, 5.05, 8.15, 10.55, 1.05};
double average;
double total = 0.0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
total += prices;
}

System.out.println("Sum of all prices: "+total+"\n" );
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
if (prices <= 5.00){
System.out.println(prices + " is less than $5.00");
}
}
average = total / (20);
System.out.println("\nThe average price is " + average + "\n");
for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
if (prices >= average) {
System.out.println( " Values above average: " + prices);
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: ``total += prices;``? What is that supposed to mean? Prices is an array and total is a double.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since prices is an array (double[]) and 5.00 is a single double, it makes no sense to check if "prices <= 5.00". It would be like saying "If [1.2, 3.4, 5.7, 6.2, 3.4] < 5.00". So the compiler complains with that verbiage.

Updated 3/18 per follow-up question:

The short answer is to replace the prices variable with the prices[i] variable to match the iteration that checks each spot since this appears to be the goal of the computation. Also, you don't need to declare "i" at the top level. You can do that per for-loop so one loop doesn't accidentally affect another loop.

```
public class Prices {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Set up a list of TEST prices to check for various conditions
        double[] prices = { 2.45, 7.85, 1.35, 1.55, 4.05, 9.55, 4.55, 1.45, 7.85, 1.25, 5.55, 10.95, 8.55,
                2.85, 11.05, 1.95, 5.05, 8.15, 10.55, 1.05 };
        
        int numberOfPrices = prices.length;
        
        // GOAL: Calculate Sum of all numbers
        // For each price (i=0, 1, 2... 19), add THAT price to the current value of total
        double total = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrices; i++) {
            total += prices[i];
        }
        System.out.println("Sum of all prices: " + total + "\n");
        
        // GOAL: Check for for those less than 5
        // For each price (i=0, 1, 2... 19), see if THAT price is less than 5.00
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrices; i++) {
            if (prices[i] <= 5.00) {
                System.out.println(prices[i] + " is less than $5.00");
            }
        }
        
        // Calculate the average price (without hard-coding)
        double average;
        // average = total / (20);
        average = total / numberOfPrices;
        System.out.println("\nThe average price is " + average + "\n");
        
        // GOAL: Check for Above Average numbers
        // For each price (i=0, 1, 2... 19), see if THAT price is above the average we computed before
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPrices; i++) {
            if (prices[i] >= average) {
                System.out.println(" Values above average: " + prices[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I redid the code above in an IDE so you could get an exact, runnable answer. This is basically what Harsh suggested previously with some other minor alterations.

Comment: Also, for future questions, please format your code in a pretty printer or IDE/Editor when posting as it makes it easier to visually debug.

Answer (score 0):

`prices` is an array. How can Java tell what you mean by asking if 20 different doubles are less than 9? Are they all less than 9? Are they less than 9 combined? Are any of them individually less than 9?

It's not a good comparison. Your operands are bad.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to write `prices[i]` instead of `prices` in most places